# Custom properties data is not transferred from application insight to oms through application insight connector

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-oms

Application insight connector in oms is not pulling custom properties that were logged in application insight.

I have application where i write additional request specific context data in custom properties when calling trace, error, warning methods.

In oms i want to filter based on these custom properties.

eg : all my micro services api emit correlation id in custom properties and this correlation id is maintained when call goes from one api to other api. This will help to correlated user request for a workflow.

But when my appinsight data from all microservice appinsight comes to oms those custom properties are lost.

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

One approach i noted is by exporting app-insight logs to blob storage and then configuring oms to get logs from blob storage.

I have not tried this approach but looks like one option. wanted to check if anybody faced this situation and what helped.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach i got after some more reading is to use log analytics http data collector api to log all data directly to log analytics. This envolves lot of work to change application logger to use http data api. It sounds possible to but doesnt feels right to make so much change.

App ->  http data api -> log analytics
app ->  appinsight ->  connector -> loganalytics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api